# iphone obj-c error: Assignment to read-only property when using Core Plot

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot

So I'm trying to create some graphs using Core Plot, but for the following lines of code:

```
CPTLineStyle *lineStyle = [[[CPTLineStyle lineStyle] alloc] init];
[lineStyle lineColor] = [CPTColor blackColor];
[lineStyle lineWidth] = 2.0f;
```

I'm getting an "Assignment to readonly property" error (for the second and thir lines), when clearly lineColor and lineWidth are assignable properties.  I've been racking my brain about this for some time now, so hopefully someone knows what the issue might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use CPTMutableLineStyle, all of the properties in CPTLineStyle are read-only and can only be set when initializing the LineStyle.
And your syntax for setting the properties is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with Core Plot. Your syntax is wrong. Either:

```
[lineStyle setLineColor:[CPTColor blackColor]];
[lineStyle setLineWidth:2.0f];
```

or:

```
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
```

Comment: I tried the second way initially and that gave the same error, but when I do `[lineStyle setLineColor:[CPTColor blackColor]];` I get the warning: "CPTLineStyle may not respond to setLineColor".  Any idea what that means?

Comment: You have to `#import` the appropriate header file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've already got the right imports, i.e. the `"CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"` file, and the first line initializing `lineStyle` gives no errors.

Comment: In that case, these properties of `CPTLineStyle` probably *are* indeed read-only, as the compiler has told you all along. A quick look in the header file should confirm that.